# помогите с массивами php

Tags: php, массивы, datetime

у меня есть  array

```
Array ( 
  [0] => Array ( [0] => 2018,07,02 [1] => 0.56 ) 
  [1] => Array ( [0] => 2018,07,04 [1] => 0.56 ) 
  [2] => Array ( [0] => 2018,07,04 [1] => 2.29 ) 
  [3] => Array ( [0] => 2018,08,22 [1] => 276.03 ) 
  [4] => Array ( [0] => 2018,08,23 [1] => 276.03 ) 
  [5] => Array ( [0] => 2018,08,23 [1] => 326.86 ) 
  [6] => Array ( [0] => 2018,08,27 [1] => 328.33 )
)
```

как поменять массив так чтоб получить тот же массив, но месяц был на 1 меньше? Пример:

```
Array ( 
 [0] => Array ( [0] => 2018,06,02 [1] => 0.56 ) 
 [1] => Array ( [0] => 2018,06,04 [1] => 0.56 ) 
 [2] => Array ( [0] => 2018,06,04 [1] => 2.29 ) 
 [3] => Array ( [0] => 2018,07,22 [1] => 276.03 ) 
 [4] => Array ( [0] => 2018,07,23 [1] => 276.03 ) 
 [5] => Array ( [0] => 2018,07,23 [1] => 326.86 ) 
 [6] => Array ( [0] => 2018,07,27 [1] => 328.33 )
```

)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как вариант, полный перебор массива циклом.

```
foreach($arr as &$item){
    $explodedDate = explode(',', $item[0]);
    $explodedDate[1] = (int)$explodedDate[1] - 1;
    if(mb_strlen($explodedDate[1]) == 1){
        $explodedDate[1] = '0'.$explodedDate[1];
    }
    $item[0] = implode(',', $explodedDate);
```

Попробуйте вот так.

Comment: Undefined offset: 1

Comment: explode у вас неправелно

Comment: explode( ',',$item[0]) вот так надо

Comment: Да, спасибо, сейчас поправлю, по памяти ошибся. Так работает.

Comment: вот так работает смотри      foreach($price as &$item){
                $explodedDate = explode( ',',$item[0]);
                $explodedDate[1] = '0'.(int)$explodedDate[1] - 1;
                $item[0] = implode($explodedDate, ',');
            } спасибо помогло первое показанное

Comment: @Aram77778 , ваш вариант не сработает для 1-го т 10-го месяца

Comment: Тут уже нужно самому добавить нужные проверки. Я лишь показал пример, как это работает в 80% случаев. Универсальное решение допилите сами

Comment: уже сработало можеш тестировать на php online

Answer (score 0):

Можно распарсить дату через strtotime

```
foreach ($array as &$item) {
   $item[0] = date("Y,m,d", strtotime("-1 month", strtotime(str_replace(",", "-", $item[0]))))
}
```